# Better way to say "Sorry I asked"

Tags: phrases, connotation

I ran into a situation at work where I had some property I needed to get rid of so I asked our property manager whether I can just throw it away or if there if I need to give it to her to deal with. Her response implied that I could have just thrown them away, but since I asked in writing then she has to do things the official way. My first instinct was to respond with

> Sorry I asked!

as an apology for causing more work for her. However I realized the usual connotation for this phrase is annoyance that the answerer is causing more headache for the asker, and I don't want her to get the wrong meaning.

Is there a better way to phrase this to not give the wrong connotation, or am I overthinking this and it would be understood as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "Sorry I asked" may be misunderstood as rude. Perhaps

> **Sorry I inconvenienced you**, but now I know what to do.

or some variation.

Answer (score 2):

The normal interpretation of "Sorry I asked!" would be "Your answer has made my life more complicated and difficult, and I regret asking the question."

If you didn't mean that, but instead simply wanted to apologize for asking something that in retrospect you could have worked out the answer to, then say something like.

> I apologize for inconveniencing/bothering/disturbing you.

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't mean to intrude" is a common one I hear.